# Laravel queues max attempts exceeded exception

Tags: php, laravel, queue, jobs

I really need help. Because I've searched everywhere, tried it in different ways, but I'm still missing something.
I have this error:

*local.ERROR: App\Jobs\TestJob has been attempted too many times or run too long. The job may have previously timed out. {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\Queue\MaxAttemptsExceededException(code: 0): App\Jobs\TestJob has been attempted too many times or run too long. The job may have previously timed out. at /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php:750)*

Below is how I implemented the queue.

**Creating queue:**

```
use App\Jobs\Middleware\RateLimited;

Testjob::dispatch($data, $request->callback_query)
                ->onQueue('job')->through([RateLimited::middleware('job')]);
```

**TestJob.php :**

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs\TestJob;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class SendCallbackChat2desk implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable;

    public function __construct($data, $params)
    {
        $this->data = $data;

        $this->params = $params;
    }

     public function handle()
     {
         Log::info("JOB WORKING !!!");

        //code ...
     }
}
```

**My middleware RateLimited:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiter;
use Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiting\Limit;
use Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiting\Unlimited;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

class RateLimited
{
    private RateLimiter $rateLimiter;

    public function __construct(RateLimiter $rateLimiter)
    {
        $this->rateLimiter = $rateLimiter;
    }

    public static function middleware(string $name, bool $shouldSkipOnSync = false): string
    {
        return self::class . ':' . $name . ',' . ($shouldSkipOnSync ? 'true' : 'false');
    }

    public function handle($job, \Closure $next, string $name, string $shouldSkipOnSync)
    {
        if ($job->connection === 'sync' && $shouldSkipOnSync === 'true') {
            return $next($job);
        }

        $releaseDelay = $this->calculateReleaseDelay($name, $job);

        if ($releaseDelay > 0) {
            return $job->release($releaseDelay);
        }

        return $next($job);
    }

    private function calculateReleaseDelay(string $name, $job): int
    {
        $limiters = Collection::make($this->resolvetRateLimit($name, $job))->filter();

        $releaseDelay = $limiters->reduce(function (int $releaseDelay, Limit $limit) {
            if ($limit instanceof Unlimited) {
                return $releaseDelay;
            }

            if ($this->rateLimiter->tooManyAttempts($limit->key, $limit->maxAttempts)) {
                return \max($this->limitWillBeAvaialableIn($limit), $releaseDelay);
            }

            return $releaseDelay;
        }, 0);

        if ($releaseDelay === 0) {
            $limiters->each(function (Limit $limit) {
                $this->rateLimiter->hit($limit->key, $limit->decayMinutes * 60);
            });
        }

        return $releaseDelay;
    }

    private function resolvetRateLimit(string $name, $job): array
    {
        $callback = $this->rateLimiter->limiter($name);

        if (\is_null($callback)) {
            return [];
        }

        return Arr::wrap(\call_user_func($callback, $job));
    }

    private function limitWillBeAvaialableIn(Limit $limit): int
    {
        return ($this->rateLimiter->availableIn($limit->key) ?? 0) + 5;
    }
}
```

**AppServiceProvider:**

```
use Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiting\Limit;
use Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiter;

    public function boot(RateLimiter $rateLimiter)
    {
        $rateLimiter->for('job', static function () {
            return Limit::perMinute(1)->by('job');
        });
    }
```

**queue.php:**

```
        'database' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'jobs',
            'queue' => 'default',
            'retry_after' => 90,
            'after_commit' => false,
        ],
```

> QUEUE_CONNECTION=database